# How to load PKCS7 (.p7b) file in java

Tags: java, security, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I have a `pkcs7` file, and I want to load it and extract its contents.

I tried these two methods:

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("myfile.p7b"));
FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);

//Creating PKCS7 object
PKCS7 pkcs7Signature = new PKCS7(bytes);
```

or this

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("myfile.p7b"));
PKCS7 pkcs7Signature = new PKCS7(fis);
```

but I got `IOException: Sequence tag error`

So how can I load this .p7b file ?

Comment: Which package is your `PKCS7` class from?

Comment: @mkl The package is sun.security.pkcs .

Comment: But I think that  Sun JCE has no direct support to PKCS#. Finally I used BouncyCastle library. I will post my solution in the answer section.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I did it with BouncyCastle library.

PKCS#7 is a complex format, also called CMS. Sun JCE has no direct support to PKCS#7.

This is the code that I used to extract my content:

```
// Loading the file first
   File f = new File("myFile.p7b");
   byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) f.length()];
   DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
   in.readFully(buffer);
   in.close();

   //Corresponding class of signed_data is CMSSignedData
   CMSSignedData signature = new CMSSignedData(buffer);
   Store cs = signature.getCertificates();
   SignerInformationStore signers = signature.getSignerInfos();
   Collection c = signers.getSigners();
   Iterator it = c.iterator();

   //the following array will contain the content of xml document
   byte[] data = null;

   while (it.hasNext()) {
        SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) it.next();
        Collection certCollection = cs.getMatches(signer.getSID());
        Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();
        X509CertificateHolder cert = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next();

        CMSProcessable sc = signature.getSignedContent();
        data = (byte[]) sc.getContent();
    }
```

If you want to verify the signature of this PKCS7 file against X509 certificate, you must add the following code to the while loop:

```
// ************************************************************* //
// ********************* Verify signature ********************** //
//get CA public key
// Create a X509 certificat
CertificateFactory certificatefactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

// Open the certificate file
FileInputStream fileinputstream = new FileInputStream("myCA.cert");

//get CA public key
PublicKey pk = certificatefactory.generateCertificate(fileinputstream).getPublicKey();

X509Certificate myCA = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(cert);

myCA.verify(pk);
System.out.println("Verfication done successfully ");
```

Comment: I have a p7 object using forgejs in javascript. Now I want to parse that p7 object in java. How should I do that? Should I write json string of object to a file and use that file in java?

Comment: Do you have any idea why I am getting "CMSException: IOException reading content" while trying to read a p7b file? Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks