# How to read a p7b file programmatically in java

Tags: java, x509certificate, keystore, p7b

I have .p7b file in my local storage (C:\Users\Certs\cert.p7b).
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118893/how-to-load-pkcs7-p7b-file-in-java) solution is not working for me.

I tried the following.

```
File file = new File("C:\Users\Certs\cert.p7b");
BufferedInputStream bis = null;
try {
     byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
     DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
     in.readFully(buffer);
     in.close();
     CertificateFactory certificatefactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
     X509Certificate cert = certificatefactory.getCertificate(in);
}catch (Exception e){
     System.out.println("Exception");
}
```

But it is not working. So how can I load this .p7b file and then store it in a keystore.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118893/how-to-load-pkcs7-p7b-file-in-java)?

Comment: I have already mentioned that the said duplicate answer is not helpful for me.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I get this error ```java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To read the certificates out of PKCS#7 file, you can use this code snippet:

```
public static final Certificate[] readCertificatesFromPKCS7(byte[] binaryPKCS7Store) throws Exception
{
    try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(binaryPKCS7Store);)
    {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        Collection<?> c = cf.generateCertificates(bais);

        List<Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<Certificate>();

        if (c.isEmpty())
        {
            // If there are now certificates found, the p7b file is probably not in binary format.
            // It may be in base64 format.
            // The generateCertificates method only understands raw data.
        }
        else
        {

            Iterator<?> i = c.iterator();

            while (i.hasNext())
            {
                certList.add((Certificate) i.next());
            }
        }

        java.security.cert.Certificate[] certArr = new java.security.cert.Certificate[certList.size()];

        return certList.toArray(certArr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, always_a_rookie_to_learn. This is the only solution on the whole internet I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You closed the InputStream.  You can’t read from it after that.

You should not be using a DataInputStream.  You should not be using a buffer.  Just open the file and let the CertificateFactory and read from it:

```
X509Certificate cert = null;
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Certs\\cert.p7b");
try (InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
     CertificateFactory certificatefactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
     cert = certificatefactory.generateCertificate(in);
} catch (CertificateException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

***Always*** print or log the full stack trace of a caught exception.  You want to know what’s going wrong, after all.  Hiding it will not help your program, will not help you, and will not help us.

In the future, please post your actual code.  It’s hard to know which lines are causing a problem if we can’t see them.